# java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

I am trying to implement Revenuecat to my app . When i tried to purchase i am getting this error :

> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetails

In this Line : `Purchases.getSharedInstance().purchaseProduct(this, (SkuDetails) skuList, new MakePurchaseListener() {`

I am trying to buy only a product . Can anyone help me to solve this ? Their sdk reference is in Kotlin . I asked for help they are not helping .

Here is the code :

```
Show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           // relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
            skuList.add(ITEM_S);


            Purchases.getSharedInstance().getNonSubscriptionSkus(skuList, new GetSkusResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onReceived(@NonNull List<SkuDetails> skus) {
                    makepurchase(skus);


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@NonNull PurchasesError error) {

                }
            });






        }

    });




private void makepurchase(List<SkuDetails> skuList){

        Purchases.getSharedInstance().purchaseProduct(this, (SkuDetails) skuList, new MakePurchaseListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(@NonNull Purchase purchase, @NonNull PurchaserInfo purchaserInfo) {


                Toast.makeText(UserInformation.this,"Purchase complete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull PurchasesError error, boolean userCancelled) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in `onReceived` you're passing `List<SkuDetails> skuList` to the method expecting `List<String>` - it should be:

```
private void makepurchase(List<SkuDetails> skuList) {
}
```

Then, depending on your context you should iterate over the skuList and purchase each item separately, or modify signature of `Purchases.getSharedInstance().purchaseProduct` to work with `List<SkuDetails>`

Update: iterating the `skuList` to purchase each skuItem separately.

Negative side effect: as many messages `Purchase complete` as the size of the skuList

```java
  private void makepurchase(List<SkuDetails> skuList) {
    for (SkuDetails skuItem : skuList) {
      Purchases.getSharedInstance()
        .purchaseProduct(this, skuItem, new MakePurchaseListener() {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(
                  @NonNull Purchase purchase, @NonNull PurchaserInfo purchaserInfo) {

                Toast.makeText(UserInformation.this, "Purchase complete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }

              @Override
              public void onError(@NonNull PurchasesError error, boolean userCancelled) {}
            });
      }
  }
```

Comment: Check my question i have added the line where i am getting error.

Comment: Updated the answer with the details how to iterate over `skuList`.  If it's not that convenient, you'll need to modify `Purchases.getSharedInstance().purchaseProduct` to accept the list of `SkuDetails` products - now it is accepting only one product.